# R: how to query from a database multiple times based on different dates

Tags: r, postgresql

I have an R Markup file in which I establish a database connection, query data, and store the data in an csv file. The query is based on a specific date range. How can I automated make multiple queries, so that one after another e.g. every week is queried from the database? I cannot make a query for e.g. the whole year, but I need to store the data separately for each week. I could make a data frame, in which I have two columns for the start and end date, which I would like to use for the query.

But how can I automatically run the queries multiple times depending on the date data frame?

My code so far:

```
#load libraries

drv <- PostgreSQL()
db_con <- dbConnect(drv, host=my_host, user=my_user, dbname=my_name, port=my_port, password=my_password)

start = "2015-01-01"
end = "2015-01-02"

result <- dbGetQuery(
db_con, 
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= start AND date <= end;")

st_write(result, pathname)
```

Comment: Your current code could not have worked to query data since `start` and `end` are unrecognized identifiers to Postgres engine though they are assigned in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider parameterization using `DBI::sqlInterpolate` with a `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) iteration:

```r
db_con <- dbConnect(
             PostgreSQL(), host=my_host, user=my_user, dbname=my_name, 
             port=my_port, password=my_password)
          )

# ALL WEEKLY DATES IN 2015
dates_df <- data.frame(
                 start=seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by="week"),
                 end=seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-08"), as.Date("2016-01-08"), by="week")
            )

# USER DEFINED METHOD TO QUERY AND WRITE DATA
query_db <- function(s, e) {
   # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PLACEHOLDERS
   sql <- "SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= ?start AND date <= ?end;"

   # BIND PARAMETERS AND QUERY
   stmt <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(db_con, sql, start=s, end=e)
   result <- dbGetQuery(db_con, stmt)

   # WRITE DATA TO DISK 
   st_write(result, pathname)

   # RETURN QUERY RESULTSET
   return(result)
}

# WRITE AND STORE DATA IN MEMORY
df_list <- Map(query_db, dates_df$start, dates_df$end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `DBI::dbBind` and a frame (similar to @Parfait's answer).

For demonstration, I have a "sessions" table on my pg instance that has a field `ScheduledStart`. In this case, it's a `TIMESTAMPTZ` column, not a `Date` column, so I need to take one more step in my demo (convert from R's `Date` to `POSIXt` classes).

```r
# pg <- DBI::dbConnect(...)

ranges <- data.frame(
  start = seq(as.Date("2020-03-01"), length.out = 4, by = "week")
)
ranges$end <- ranges$start + 6
# this line is only necessary because of my local table
ranges[] <- lapply(ranges, as.POSIXct)
```

Here is the bulk of the "query multiple weeks":

```r
res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(pg, "select count(*) as n from Sessions where ScheduledStart between ? and ?")
DBI::dbBind(res, ranges)
out <- DBI::dbFetch(res)
DBI::dbClearResult(res)
out
#   n
# 1 8
# 2 1
# 3 0
# 4 0
```

While `sqlInterpolate` is much better than forming your own query strings (e.g., with `sprintf` or `paste`), using `dbBind` allows for internal iteration like above, and allows the DBMS to optimize the query with the binding parameter `?` instead of actual data. (Using `sqlInterpolate`, the DBMS would see four different queries. Using `dbBind`, it sees one query, optimizes it, and uses it four times.)

That query was really boring (`select * ...` works, too), but I think it gets the point across. The only downside of this method is that while it makes it really easy to get all of the data, there is nothing here that inherently tells you which of your queries a particular row came from. I suspect that you can determine that from your data, that your main intent on breaking it down by-week is the amount retrieved per-query.

Side note: I often use code like this *in functions*, where it is feasible that something between `dbSendQuery` and `dbClearResult` might interrupt operation. In that case, I tend to reorder my code a little, like this:

```r
somefunc <- function(...) {
  # ...
  res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(pg, "select count(*) as n from Sessions where ScheduledStart between ? and ?")
  on.exit({
    suppressWarnings(DBI::dbClearResult(res))
  }, add = TRUE)
  DBI::dbBind(res, ranges)
  DBI::dbClearResult(res)
  return(out)
}
```